# System32 files missing

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, 32-bit

This may seem a unusual request but I need someone to give or help me find a system32 folder, for Windows 7 ultimate 32-bit. I have damaged a lot of the files and it is now failing to boot. Can anyone give me a download link please. I am currently sending this post from a boot-able Linux disk and I have looked on Google but I have found nothing.

**EDIT:** The EXE files are fine it is just some of the DLLs are missing. I also have a Windows 7 ultimate 32bit ISO image.

Comment: Simply replacing these files are unlikely to do anything unless you find exactly the right version of the dll.

Comment: Run this command from a command prompt with administrator rights: `sfc /scannow`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to repair your windows installation using a windows repair disc.

You may also use the following site for your [missing dll files](http://www.dll-files.com/)